# Expect script to automatically log in, command and show its output

Tags: expect

I'm new to scripting and need some help. I am creating an expect script that from a Linux server, that will automatically `ssh/log` in to our HP StoreOnce Appliance

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
set password "password"
match_max 1000
spawn ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no user@10.x.x.x
expect "*?assword:*"
send -- "$password\r"
send -- "\r"
interact
```

When executing this script, I was able to automatically login and from there I can type the commands.

Please see output below:

```
=================================================================
[root@dpis tmp]# ./test.exp
spawn ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no user@10.x.x.x
Password:
Last login: Thu Jan 26 08:37:24 2017 from 10.x.x.x

Welcome to the HP StoreOnce Backup System Command Line Interface.
Type 'help' at the prompt for context-sensitive help.

>
```

But what I want to achieve is for the script to not only automatically log-in but also automatically put a command and show its output then exit.

I tried to add the following lines below after interact

```
expect ">"

send -- "serviceset show status"
```

Seeking assistance on how to achieve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have a good start. After you get expect to type the command, you have to hit Enter (send the character `\r`). Then you have to expect another prompt so the results can be displayed

```
expect ">"
send -- "serviceset show status\r"
expect ">"
```

Capturing output in expect is a bit of a PITA. You can do something like this:

```
# at the top of the program
log_user 0
# ... log in ...
expect ">"

set cmd "serviceset show status\r"
send -- $cmd
expect -re "$cmd\n(.*)\r\n>"
set output $expect_out(1,string)
puts $output

# disconnect
send -- "exit\r"
expect eof
```

Comment: Hi glenn, got an error when I used your suggestion for capturing output. However I can now display my result using your first suggestion then exit. Is it possible to convert the output of my command into a .txt file then send it to the Linux server's /var/tmp wherein I executed it? Can you assist me with that? Thanks

Comment: You could either just redirect the output of the script (`expect script.exp > /var/tmp/file.txt`) or use the expect `log_file` command.