# Opening an application and inputting a command in one line

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, scripting

I have developed an application in C that is a command line. The app has special keywords to output information. Currently I need to run a command to log into my application, than run a command to get an output, and finally exit the application.

Is there a way to combine my 3 lines into one? For Example, login, enter command, and exit sequentially? As you can see in the example below, if I can do this all in one line I wouldn't need to manually input every step.

```
./application -login user@192.168.65.10
> getstats
> exit    
./application -login user@192.168.65.11
> getstats
> exit
etc...
```

What I want is something like...

```
./application -login user@192.168.65.10 && getstats && exit
```

Of course && is not what I'm looking for as it runs each command one at a time until. getstats and exit don't get run inside the .application but rather after I exit out of it...

Any tips would be great.

Comment: Not very professional, but just for testing give a try to something like : `./application -login user@192.168.65.10; sleep 5 && echo "getstats" &; sleep 10 && echo "exit" &;`

Comment: Please specify what language the application is written in.

Comment: @agc Updated. It is developed in C

Answer (score 3):

If this application works with *standard input*, this may work:

```
printf 'getstats\nexit\n' | ./application -login user@192.168.65.10
```

If that doesn't work, you can try an `expect` script. You can see an example [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/340346/22222).

Comment: I tried this method but session seems to hang. The system I am using doesn't have expect installed and I'd prefer a method that doesn't require a external application.

Comment: @sphchow if this doesn't work `expect` is probably your only other choice.

Comment: @sphchow, The application is written in *C*.  I'd suggest reconsidering which *C* function is used to input these command words, (i.e. *getstats* & *exit*) -- some *C* input functions work well with *STDIN*,  perhaps the application can be modified to use one of those *STDIN* friendly functions.